# Ошибка при попытке сериализации класса в C#

Tags: c#, serializable

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Есть динамическая библиотека в проекте, в которой есть абстрактный базовый класс, экземпляры которого необходимо будет сериализовывать, но код выдает ошибку:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Model09
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Базовый класс, хранит дистанцию, которую преодолеет спорстмен 
    ///     или вес, который он поднимет в при занятиях штангой
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable()]
    public abstract class ActionsBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Расстояние в метрах или вес в кг в зависимости от дочерних  
        ///     классов в которых будет использована переменная
        /// </summary>
        protected double _distanceOrWeight;

        /// <summary>
        /// Табличное значение кКал, потраченных в зависимости от вида 
        ///     упражнений за 1 час на 1 кг массы тела человека
        /// </summary>
        protected double _killCalorie;

        /// <summary>
        /// Конструктор для Actions
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="distanceOrWeight">Дистанция которую преодолел
        ///     спортсмен или вес на штанге</param>
        protected ActionsBase(double distanceOrWeight)
        {
            _distanceOrWeight = distanceOrWeight;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Показывает время, затраченное на выполнение упражнения
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intensiveTraining"> Интенсивность выполнения 
        ///     упражнений</param>
        /// <returns> Время выполнения упражнений</returns>
        public virtual double GetTime(double intensiveTraining)
        {
            return _distanceOrWeight / (intensiveTraining * 1000);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Возвращает значение переменной _killcalorie 
        ///     в зависмости от интенсивности нагрузки
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intensiveTraining"> Интенсивность выполнения
        ///     упражнений</param>
        /// <returns> Потраченные калории в зависимости
        ///     от интенсивности нагрузки</returns>
        public virtual double GetKillCalorie(double intensiveTraining)
        {
            return _killCalorie;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Метод расчета количества калорий затраченных в каком-либо
        ///     упражении за все время выполнения с учетом веса
        ///         времени на упражнения и темпа выполнения
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="weightPerson"> Вес человека</param>
        /// <returns> Количество потерянных калорий</returns>
        public virtual double CountCalorie(double weightPerson)
        {
            return weightPerson * GetKillCalorie(_killCalorie)
                * GetTime(_killCalorie);
        }

        ///// <summary>
        ///// Добавление даты
        ///// </summary>
        public string Date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление вида спорта
        /// </summary>
        public string Style { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление веса спортсмена
        /// </summary>
        public string Weight { set; get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление дистанции
        /// </summary>
        public string Distance { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление скорости
        /// </summary>
        public string Speed { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление калорий
        /// </summary>
        public string Kkal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ругается на [Serializable()] "Не удалось найти Model09 тип или имя пространства имен SerializableAttribute" (возможно, отсутствует директива Using) и вторая ошибка подобная ошибка. Пробовал подключать разные ссылки на библиотеки, не помогает. 
В самом проекте создал класс Action

```
using System;

namespace WpfModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс который хранит список активностей
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class Actions
    {

        ///// <summary>
        ///// Добавление даты
        ///// </summary>
        public string Date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление вида спорта
        /// </summary>
        public string Style { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление веса спортсмена
        /// </summary>
        public string Weight{ set; get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление дистанции
        /// </summary>
        public string Distance { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление скорости
        /// </summary>
        public string Speed { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавление калорий
        /// </summary>
        public string Kkal { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Там почему-то все работает, но преподаватель не принимает, говорит, что хранение методов должно быть в ActionsBase. Подскажите, может есть какая-то отдельная библиотека которую я упускаю или абстрактный класс нельзя сериализовать?
Я уже поочередно подключил все библиотеки, что у меня были в WPF проекте в динамическую библиотеку Model09, ничего не помогает.
Ниже прилагаю ссылки на библиотеки, которые я добавил, может нужна еще какая-либо ссылка?
[image: Ссылки и дерево проекта]

Comment: Какой в свойствах проекта библиотеки установлен Target Framework? Есть ли в References проекта библиотеки System.Runtime.dll?

Comment: References проекта библиотеки System.Runtime.dll - добавлен. Target Framework - .Net Framework 4 Windows 8.

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Приложите весь класс.

Comment: LLEN, не понял коммент, написать весь класс в сообщении?

Comment: @АртемГрушев, Да, весь класс в вопрос.

Comment: @LLENN, добавил.

Comment: Проблема была в том, библиотека Model09 была создана как переносимая Target Framework был выбран - .Net Framework 4 Windows 8. Пробовал менять Target Framework, но ничего не помогло, как я понял, возможно я не прав, для того чтобы работала сериализация нужен .Net Framework 4.5.2, но его нельзя выбрать для переносимой библиотеки. Когда пересоздал Model09 как просто библиотеку классов, то возможность сериализации появилась платформа в ней .Net Framework 4.5.2.